# Remove sale prices on items in store

Tags: magento-2.1, special-price, sale-price

I am in the process of **migrating** from an older **Magento 1.7 to a Magento 2.1.5** webshop.

On the new one, after a very tricky database migration I have a weird occurrence of some products being on sale, that weren't on sale in the old webshop.

See the below links for examples, the first link is to the older webshop where the products are shown with the correct price, the second link is to the new shop where the products have been put on sale.

[Old Webshop](http://appaman.no/catalogsearch/result/?q=tilly)

[New Webshop](https://34.202.7.124/catalogsearch/result/?q=tilly)

Now I have no listings in my Catalog Price rules and Cart Price rules on my new shop, I though maybe it would be here that these sale prices are being set but it does not seem like it.

On the old shop, there are some Catalog Price Rules, so I'm thinking that during the migration of the product database might have brought some sale settings with it, I only wanted to migrate the product catalog, not sales history etc.

Could it be in the database where I will find the reason why these items that are being put on sale? I do have phpMyAdmin access and can edit the database directly if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Prices come from catalog_product_index_price.
These are calculated based on customer group, tax class special price and tier price. By looking into the table you can quickly figure out if tier pricing is the culprit or is it because if customer group. If none of these are responsible then look for special prices in catalog_product_entity_decimal.